# Validation of nested dynamic reactive form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make an Ionic 3 app with Angular 7.
I have a dynamic reactive form where a new form group is being added when you click on a button.

How do I validate the nested fields? How do I write the getter or how to address the needed field in html?

The main problem is that I have an array of the FormGroups (see PostPieces) so from Angular the validator doesn't know which PostPiece from array it refers too so I don't really know how to write a getter for this.
The form DOES get invalid BUT I can't output the message because I don't know how to the condition check in this case.

My html & angular:
[Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0SAl.png)
   [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY6tK.png)

Comment: A factory function. Create a function that takes in the validation rules as a parameter and then creates your new FormGroup, applying those rules to it. Such a function might live in a service.

Also see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation for basic feedback for the user ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Nested FormGroup Template Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459573/angular-6-nested-formgroup-template-validation)

Comment: @KeenanDiggs The problem is that angular doesn't know to which object from array to refer when checking if it's valid or no

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!

It's writing a function which would get the needed FormGroup by index and then using it in the ngIf part as usually.
[Source](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-dynamic-form-fields-using-formarray/)